# Creating HTML email with specific regions of the image clickable

Tags: html, email, html-email, email-attachments

I've been provided with an image and what is required is that image is to be sent to potential clients through email.

Now, there are specific regions in the email which should be clickable with different URL.

For e.g. The region where "Ask for Quote" is written, takes the client to the form on the website where he can enter his details. Similarly, the region where the web address of the website is mentioned on the image takes the client to the website when clicked.

How can this be done for an email?

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't advise this as if the user's email is blocking images(most do) then your email is pretty much useless

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is image `map`s

```html
<p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>

<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="#!">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="#!">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="#!">
</map>
```

However keep in mind email support or if the client has images turned off

[image: email Support]

Windows Live Hotmail no longer supports image maps. Curiously, Gmail now supports image maps in Safari, whereas it didn’t before.

Comment: So this requires image to be hosted on the web somewhere. Only then it will work. Right? I mean that you cannot send the image with the email straightaway?

Comment: Yep it has to be somewhere viewable by others